# Very Beginner Python: Replacing Part of a String

Tags: python, replace

I want to know how you can replace one letter of a string without replacing the same letter. For example, let the variable:

```
action = play sports.
```

I could substitute "play" for "playing" by doing `print(action.replace("play", "playing")`

But what if you have to of the same letters?

For example, what if you want to replace the last half of "honeyhoney" into "honeysweet" (Replacing the last half of the string to sweet?

Sorry for the bad wording, I am new to coding and really unfamiliar with this. Thanks!

Comment: You could first find all the strings in the provided input. Replace part of the strings as necessary necessary. Concatenate them after the replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def replaceLast(str, old, new):
  return str[::-1].replace(old[::-1],new[::-1], 1)[::-1]

print(replaceLast("honeyhoney", "honey", "sweet"))
```

**output**

```
honeysweet
```

so the idea is to reverse the string and the old and new substrings,
so the last substring becomes the first, do a replace and then reverse the returned string once again, and the number 1 is to replace only once and not both matches

**Another solution**

```
def replaceLast(str, old, new):
  ind = str.rfind(old)
  if ind == -1 : return str
  return str[:ind] + new + str[ind + len(old):];

print(replaceLast("honeyhoney", "honey", "sweet"))
```

**output**

```
honeysweet
```

so here we get the string from the beginning to the index of the last substring then we add the new substring and the rest of the string from where the old substring ends and return them as the new string, `String.rfind` returns -1 in case of no match found and we need to check aginst that to make sure the output is correct even if there is nothing to replace.